# Chossing a row's value based on a dropdown in sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I want to choose one of data from column B and column C based on column D to be entered in column E.

| A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jan | 100 | 200 | B | =`Formula to get 100` |
| Feb | 101 | 201 | C | =`Formula to get 201` |
| March | 102 | 202 | C | =`Formula to get 202` |
| Apil | 103 | 203 | B | =`Formula to get 103` |

Things I will do:

1. Add data validation in column D so I can change it to dropdown.
2. Data in column E should change dynamically as D is changed.

Some useful functions I found:

1. [Choose](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093371?hl=en)
2. [If](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364?hl=en)

Comment: I need values in column D to be text, and not numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have many column then use `INDEX/MATCH` combinedly-

```
=INDEX($B$2:$C,ROW()-1,MATCH(D2,$B$1:$C$1,0))
```

[image]

Comment: However I ended up using a different formula as I was getting some error with yours. 
Formula I used:
`=CHOOSE(MATCH($D2,$B$1:$C$1,0),$B2,$C2,0)`

Answer (score 1):

try in row 1:

```
=INDEX(IF(D1:D="B"; B1:B; C1:C))
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the following formula:

`=CHOOSE(MATCH($D2,$B$1:$C$1,0),$B2,$C2,0)`

[image]

Thanks to [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68608124/6448656) by harun24HR.